# How to relate 3 wordpress components with each other (Create database relationships)

Tags: plugins, posts, database

Alright, so I have these 3 website parts:

- Gallery (that has)
- Artist
- Place

A gallery can have only one artist and one place
An artist can have many galleries
A place can have many galleries

When I open a new gallery, we'll see who made it (Artist) and where it was (Place)
An artist has only the latest gallery and place displayed on his page
A place has the 3 latest artists that "were" on that place and the 3 latest galleries made there

Defining this kind of relationships in raw PHP would have been easy. But creating this in Wordpress is new to me.

What should I use to create this?

Answer (score 1):

Before you get to *relating* things in WordPress, you should decide *what* things are.

In a very nutshell there are:

1. Posts of post types (native ones being pages and blog posts)
2. Terms of taxonomies (native ones being tags and categories)

There are some things that WordPress does smoothly out of the box. Such as post being assigned a term or term having a parent term.

Others are completely missing, notably post being directly related to another post.

From your description my educated guess would be:

1. Gallery post type
2. Artist taxonomy
3. Place taxonomy

But depending on specifics of data involved there might be nuances to push it in different direction entirely. While defining taxonomies and custom post types is quite easy in WordPress, *effectively* making use of them takes a bit of practice.

Comment: What do you suggest me to do? How should I proceed to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: looks like artist and place could be a custom port type, don't you think? the main issue could be to related all post types with the same custom taxonomy with in native wordpress

Comment: Taxonomies are for _grouping_ posts, not relating. WP doesn't do post relationships natively, though third party libraries exist for it.